# z-index is not responding so menu shows under text

Tags: html, css, z-index

i've made an navigation but the z-index is not responding to is which leads to a navigator behind pictures. I can figure out why it is doing it but its just on a few  parts of the site.
http://wilpegroup.webshoptool.nl/
I hope you guys got an solution for this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add high z-index this class `fixed_content_container`

```
.fixed_content_container {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have look on your site .

i use inspector of chrome where i apply z-index:10000 to #nav_id(dive with id nav_id) .

now you navigator menu is showing on the top .

please add and try

```
#nav_id{
  z-index:10000
 }
```

in your stylesheet file or in style tag of page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer its already fixed with lalji his answer but I appreciate your time.